# How i print each second element in a list full of lines? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, line, element

I have a list of numbers like this(saved in .txt file):

```
list_of_numbers = [
   ('5', 2.5, 5200),
   ('6', 3.2, 5236),
   ('8', 5.4, 5287),
   ('6', 8.7, 2563)
]
```

And i imported this list (list is .txt file) like this:

```
list_of_numbers = open("list_of_numbers.txt").read().strip().split()
```

but now i want that python print me each second element in each line.. I tried this:

```
p = x[1] for x in list_of_numbers
print(p)
```

but it's not correct..
And i want that python printed me like this:

```
p = 2.5, 3.2, 5.4
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the brackets. Try this:

```
p = [x[1] for x in list_of_numbers]
```

To print the values, you could use

```
print(', '.join([str(x) for x in p]))
```

You also need to change the way you load the data from the file

**Full Code:**

```
def parse(raw):
    data = []
    for line in raw.split("\n"):
        line = line.strip()
        # --> "('5', 2.5, 5200)"
        if line.startswith("(") and line.endswith(")"):
            d = line[line.index("(")+1 : line.index(")", -1)]
            # --> "'5', 2.5, 5200"
            d = d.split(",")
            data.append([])
            for i in d:
                i = i.strip()
                try:
                    i = float(i)
                except:
                    pass
                data[-1].append(i)
    return data


raw = open("list_of_numbers.txt").read()

list_of_numbers = parse(raw)

p = [x[1] for x in list_of_numbers]
# --> [2.5, 3.2, 5.4, 8.7]
print(', '.join([str(x) for x in p]))
# ---> 2.5, 3.2, 5.4, 8.7
```

I suggest using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Storing and loading your data is easy as:

```
import pickle
data = ...
# store
file = open('data.txt', 'w')
pickle.dump(data, file)
file.close()
# load
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
data = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not correct.. Python says that there is a mistake..

IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Can you edit your question and state how your file looks like and how you import the data exactly?

Comment: This code works for me too, but i have another list.. saved in .txt file and it's written by lines... Maybe i didn't correcly import this file?

Comment: Just to clearify: is this first codebox of your question the exact content of your file?

Comment: I see. Importing that way will not work. I would suggest you to change the structure of your file, if you can (Just the numbers, space seperated, no empty lines at the end). You might be interested in [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store and load your data.

Comment: I would love to change the structure of my data, but i can't, because i'm learning how to programing in python for college, so i want to know solve examples like this too.. And i'm trying to solve this problem for like 1 week, but now im giving up, that's why i'm asking here..

Comment: I see. Readin in that data is not a trivial task. You'd have to write a parser for that specific structure. Let me see what I can do...

Comment: Aha. Thank you so much! You helpped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

```
import numpy as np
list_of_numbers = [
    ('5', 2.5, 5200),
    ('6', 3.2, 5236),
    ('8', 5.4, 5287),
    ]
list_of_numbers = np.array(list_of_numbers)
p = list_of_numbers[:,1]
print(p)
# outputs: ['2.5' '3.2' '5.4']
```

In addition, since you're reading data from a text file, your first list should contain only `str`. (I really don’t understand how you get mixed strings and numbers using the method you describe in your question.) To fix that, you can either:

- use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html),
- convert to `float` when switching to a ndarray: `np.array(list_of_numbers, dtype=float).

Finally, I strongly suggest that you learn about [slices in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my python says that there's no module named numpy..

Comment: That’s because it’s not a core library, you need to install it on your own. You'll easily find instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you for your help.